# MySQL connection/query make file not work

Tags: python, mysql

I've got some test code I'm working on. In a separate HTML file, a button onclick event gets the URL of the page and passes it as a variable (jquery_input) to this python script. Python then scrapes the URL and identifies two pieces of data, which it then formats and concatenates together (resulting in the variable lowerCaseJoined). This concatenated variable has a corresponding entry in a MySQL database. With each entry in the db, there is an associated .gif file.

From here, what I'm trying to do is open a connection to the MySQL server and query the concatenated variable against the db to get the associated .gif file.

Once this has been accomplished, I want to print the .gif file as an alert on the webpage.

If I take out the db section of the code (connection, querying), the code runs just fine. Also, I am successfully able to execute the db part of the code independently through the Python shell. However, when the entire code resides in one file, nothing happens when I click the button. I've systematically removed the lines of code related to the db connection, and my code begins stalling out at the first line (db = MySQLdb.connection...). So it looks like as soon as I start trying to connect to the db, the program goes kaput.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import urllib
import re
import cgi, cgitb 
import MySQLdb
cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

# the cgi library gets the var from the .html file
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
jquery_input = form.getvalue("stuff_for_python", "nothing sent")

# the next section scrapes the URL, 
# finds the call no and location, 
# formats them, and concatenates them
content = urllib.urlopen(jquery_input).read()
soup = Soup(content)

extracted = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": "bibItemsEntry"})
cleaned = str(extracted)

start = cleaned.find('browse') +8
end = cleaned.find('</a>', start)
callNo = cleaned[start:end]

noSpacesCallNo = callNo.replace(' ', '')
noSpacesCallNo2 = noSpacesCallNo.replace('.', '')

startLoc = cleaned.find('field 1') + 13
endLoc = cleaned.find('</td>', startLoc)
location = cleaned[startLoc:endLoc]
noSpacesLoc = location.replace(' ', '')

joined = (noSpacesCallNo2+noSpacesLoc)

lowerCaseJoined = joined.lower()

# the next section establishes a connection 
# with the mySQL db and queries it 
# using the call/loc code (lowerCaseJoined)
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="...", "passwd="...",
db="locations")
cur = db.cursor()
queryDb = """
SELECT URL FROM locations WHERE location = %s
"""
cur.execute(queryDb, lowerCaseJoined)
result = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
db.close()


# the next 2 'print' statements are important for web
print "Content-type: text/html"
print

print result
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm new at programming, so I'm sure there's a lot that can be improved upon here. But prior to refining it I just want to get the thing to work!

Comment: Have you tried adding `print` statements throughout the questionable part of the code, such as after the `db = ...` line and the `cur = ...` line and the `cur.execute ...` line just to see how far the code is getting?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Seems that I had quotation mark before the password portion of the db connection line. Things are all good now.